# UISearchBar behavior on click

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, click, uisearchbar

I have two views, both created via XIB.  One view has a search bar that behaves strangely

This search bar when clicked looks like:

!http://imgur.com/5OuAp1A,TrhZ5yV,PQjYfqw#1

(search bar turns black and seemingly takes over nav bar)

This is the behavior I expect and intend on creating:

!http://imgur.com/5OuAp1A,TrhZ5yV,PQjYfqw#2

I apologize for the trivial question, but I cannot for the life of me find the correct property that changes this search bar behavior.

Comment: U want search bar under the navigation bar, and it doesn't have any border , only search textField.r8?

Comment: Would you mind sharing code?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try changing the color of the navigation bar?

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Comment: I've made some progress, by setting the navigations transluscent property to no I no longer get that weird black view.  Now my only issue is the search view blocking the navigation bar..